# Listening for Git Repo Changes

Tags: git, push

I want to write an app that given a user's GitHub account information and a repo will be notified whenever the repo is pushed to. I know I could basically save the state of the repo and poll it for changes periodically but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a push architecture and if so how to go about it. Thanks for any help!

EDIT - I know I can probably doing this like Heroku does it by having them push to a remote server, but the ideal functionality is to know when they push to Github itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to perform an action when a `push` is received, you can write a script and use it as a `post-receive` hook. GitHub supports git-hooks, but for obvious reasons they do not allow you to write a "custom script". What their script do is actually simple - they notify you by POSTing a JSON to an URL you specify. See [their documentation](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/).

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically so the user doesn't actually have to enter in the url to post to?

Comment: @dshipper: The best you can do is to automatically change the respective repository configuration on GitHub. Maybe you want to check their APIs?

Answer (score 1):

One way which:

- wouldn't involve the main contributor of a repo to enter anything
- would allow you to define what you want to monitor

is to use:

- 2011 (since discontinued) [Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) services (and then write an app getting the result of said pipes), like the [Friend Stalker pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=85709214354b9319d6e345be3c1a6c46) described by [nefariousdesign](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/archive/2011/02/stalking-friends-on-github/).
- 2020 alternatives like [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), and, for instance:

  - [racket/email-notifications](https://github.com/racket/email-notifications)
  - other [notifications and messages actions](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#notifications-and-messages)

Comment: Yahoo Pipe no more exists, so do its links.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Good point. I have updated the answer with a more current solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [post-receive hooks](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/)

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically so the user doesn't actually have to enter in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use GitHub Service Hooks?

[Post-Receive Hooks](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/)

Comment: Is there a way to do that programmatically so the user doesn't actually have to enter in the data?